# readChar() method displays blank outside a for loop?

Tags: java, arrays, netbeans

I was populating a JList with an array, but my main problem is that the variable that's supposed to contain chars is always empty; readChar() is not getting anything, at least that's what I'm assuming.

I'm reading a database from a direct file, the content is not important except for the first two data that are read from each register: 1 int and 25 chars.

If something was read out incorrectly, I would've already noticed by looking at a display full of illegible characters...

```
public static void WritingInJList (JList x) throws IOException
   {
 try{
   RandomAccessFile file = new RandomAccessFile("database.dat","rw");

long registerSize = 78;
long numberRegisters = file.length()/registerSize;
int num=0;
String description="";

String productlist[] = new String[(int) numberRegisters];

for (int i=0;i<numberRegisters;i++)
{
   file.seek(registerSize*i);
   num = file.readInt();          /* int is read correctly */
   for (int j=0; j<25; j++)
   {description =""+file.readChar();} 
    productList[i] = num+"..."+description; /*variable description is blank!*/
    System.out.println(productList[i]); 
  }
  x.setListData(productList);
   }catch (FileNotFoundException e){System.out.println("File Not Found");}  
}
```

run:
1...
2...
3...
4...
5...
6...
7...
8...
9...
10...
11...
12...
13...

When I tracked down the problem using System.out.print();, all chars were shown if printed from inside the loop. This was the code, and the output:

```
public static void WritingInJList (JList x) throws IOException
   {
 try{
   RandomAccessFile file = new RandomAccessFile("database.dat","rw");

long registerSize = 78;
long numberRegisters = file.length()/registerSize;
int num=0;
String description="";

String productlist[] = new String[(int) numberRegisters];

for (int i=0;i<numberRegisters;i++)
{
   file.seek(registerSize*i);
   num = file.readInt();

   System.out.print(num+"...");          
   for (int j=0; j<25; j++)
     {System.out.print(""+file.readChar());} /*All chars are read perfectly*/
   System.out.println("");

   productList[i] = description; 
  }
  x.setListData(productList);
   }catch (FileNotFoundException e){System.out.println("File Not Found");}  
}
```

run:

1...product1
2...product2
3...product3
4...product4
5...product5
6...product6
7...product7
8...product8
9...product9
10...product10
11...product11
12...product12
13...product13

What am I doing wrong? Why doesn't the variable *description* display anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have:

```
for (int j=0; j<25; j++)
   {description =""+file.readChar();}
```

This resets `description` to the single character every time through the loop. Effectively this ends up leaving `description` equal to only the final character.

You probably meant something more along the lines of:

```
description="";
for (int j=0; j<25; j++)
   {description =description+file.readChar();}
```

Comment: Ugh, I feel so stupid. That's right, I meant to write 

    description =description+file.readChar();

About your suggestion, I'll consider reading bytes instead of chars. Good observation, thanks a lot.

Comment: I actually edited out my suggestion because it was incorrect, but it seems you saw it. I had forgotten that `RandomAccessFile.readChar()` is specified as always reading two bytes. Therefore, while it doesn't hurt to be mindful of encoding, there is no risk of non-fixed-size data (it will always be 50 bytes for 25 chars as long as you are using a `RandomAccessFile` -- the behavior is different from most other text input streams). Sorry for being misleading on that.